# How to insert data into the DOM using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this code in JS. Please tell me how i can increment a piece of this code so that articles are automatically inserted into HTML.
It is necessary that the data index [0] is incremented for example data [0], data [1], data [2] and beyond. title, author, content vary depending on the index number.Thanks!

```js
document.querySelector(".title").textContent = data[1]["title"];
    document.querySelector(".author").textContent = data[1]["author"]["username"];
    document.querySelector(".content").textContent = data[1]["content"];
```

```js
fetch("https://any-site/articles")
  .then(function(resp) {
    return resp.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    document.querySelector(".title").textContent = data[1]["title"];
    document.querySelector(".author").textContent = data[1]["author"]["username"];
    document.querySelector(".content").textContent = data[1]["content"];
  })
  .catch(function() {
    //catch any errors
  });
  
  
  // ---------- JSON on SITE ----------
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Some title",
      "content": "Some content",
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Leo",
      },
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Some title2",
        "content": "Some content2",
        "author": {
          "id": 2,
          "username": "Vernon",
        },
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Some title3",
        "content": "Some content3",
        "author": {
          "id": 2,
          "username": "Vernon",
        },
      },
  ]
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>News</h1>
  <h2 class="title"></h2>
  <h5 class="author"></h5>
  <p class="content"></p>
</body>
<script src="data.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems that you need to learn basic JS constructs, like for-loops before you can try to do more complex things.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method I've found is to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the data and produce some HTML using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and then insert that into the document body with [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"title":"Some title","content":"Some content","author":{"id":1,"username":"Leo"}},{"id":2,"title":"Some title2","content":"Some content2","author":{"id":2,"username":"Vernon"}},{"id":3,"title":"Some title3","content":"Some content3","author":{"id":2,"username":"Vernon"}}];

function getHTML(data) {

  // Iterate over the array of objects
  return data.map((block) => {

    // Destructure the title, author username, and content
    // from the object
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
    const { title, author: { username }, content }  = block;

    // For each object return those variables
    // in a template literal
    return `
      <div class="block">
        <p class="title">${title}</p>
        <p class="author">${username}</p>
        <p class="content">${content}</p>
      </div>
    `;

  // `map` returns an array of information so make
  // you join it up into one string of data
  }).join('');
}

// Call the `getHTML` function with the data and insert
// it on the element you want
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', getHTML(data));
```

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid #454545;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.title { text-decoration: underline; }
.author { color: blue; }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>News</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Upvoted. Worth mentioning though that this could be vulnerable to XSS when fetching unsanitized data. Using [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) should help with that.